# Identify a URL as a homepage, given various regions

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

I'd like to identify a string as a homepage (as opposed to a secondary page within the domain). It needs to be able to handle the regional variations in homepage URLs. I'm currently using `length` and `split_part` and selecting those returning zero length, but perhaps there's a more robust and/or efficient approach?

```
select length(split_part('http://home.com/','/',4)) ;            -- homepage yes
select length(split_part('http://home.co.uk/','/',4)) ;          -- homepage yes
select length(split_part('http://home.com/page2.html','/',4)) ;  -- homepage no
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following regex to identify homepages in Redshift

```
select REGEXP_SUBSTR(your_url, '[^/]+\\.[^/:]+')
```

Update :

The following SQL will give you True or False based on URL, it might not be prettier than what you have but works

```
SELECT CASE 
  WHEN POSITION('/' IN SUBSTRING(your_url,POSITION('/' IN your_url)+2,LENGTH(your_url)))
  THEN FALSE
  ELSE TRUE END
```

Comment: This appears to extract the homepage URL from a secondary page URL, is that correct? I may not have posed the question well. I would like to identify *if* a URL is a homepage.

Comment: I think I misunderstood your question, updated with a SQL gives you `True` or `False`